# Why are there two articles in front of a noun?

Tags: article

While reading a passage about language acquisition, I saw two articles in front of a single noun, and I'm a bit confused. Does it mean "to the first language" or something else, could you please explain this kind of usage in German?

> Basierend auf dem nativistischen Ansatz geht die Identitätshypothese davon aus,  dass der Erwerb der Zweitsprache im Prinzip **dem der** Erstsprache gleicht.

Comment: The "article" is in fact serving as a pronoun, as the der words can do.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The referent of the masculine dative relative pronoun *dem* is *Erwerb* and *der* is a feminine genitive article for *Erstsprache*.

> - … dass der Erwerb der Zweitsprache im Prinzip **dem** [Erwerb] der Erstsprache gleicht.
> - … the acquisition of the second language in principle resembles **that of** the first language.

This is somewhat more natural in German than in English.

Answer (score 9):

Actually a substantive is suppressed. Fully it would read:

> dass der Erwerb der Zweitsprache im Prinzip dem [Erwerb] der Erstsprache gleicht

A construction like this relies on the fact, that only one masculine or neuter (since feminine would require *der*) substantive is present, which it can refer to.

As you already noted, German scientific texts often don't show an intention to find a phrasing which is easy to grasp.